# The "違います" in the phrase "やる気が違います"

Tags: words, meaning

I am  really confused with the phrase "やる気が違います" that I saw used as a Twitter hashtag. The literal meaning is: "The motivation is different (than usual or average?)"

Is there some subtle nuance in the meaning of "違います" that I am not aware of? Or does it simply mean "The motivation is wrong (or misdirected)"?

Answer (score 5):

A good first question!

It would only benefit you to be able to use 「[違]{ちが}う」 for this rather important meaning.  ***It means "better", "at a higher level", etc.***, which is almost the opposite of what you were thinking.

> 「やる[気]{き}が違います。」
>
> thus, means "Our/My motivation is higher than theirs/others'."

Depending on the context, it could also mean "Our/My motivation is higher than before."

This 「違う」 is used quite often in advertisement as well as in our everyday conversations (for example 「やっぱりプロは違います」).

See definition ちが・う〔ちがふ〕【違う】一-1-㋑ in [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%81%95%E3%81%86-559103#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) :「両者の間に隔たりがある。差がある。また、**他と異なって[勝]{まさ}っている**。」

Comment: Ah..... So the 「違う」 in this phrase means "something different in a better way".... Ugh.... It hard to guess the subtle context....
Thanks for the help...
Should I mark this question as answered or should I wait for another question?

Comment: @SatoriWita If you replace verb "to differ" with a noun "difference", it gets similar to other languages. For example "Ford. Feel the difference". The "difference" here is undoubtedly intended to be positive, although taken literally shouldn't be.